# Access folder shares via python in android buildozer

Tags: python, kivymd, buildozer

I'm trying to access a shared folder on the lan, from the cell phone using python and kivymd and creating the application in buildozer

but on the computer it finds the folder, but on android it does not find it

I already tried the OS library, SMB
buildozer.spec has permissions and dependencies are installed

buildozer.spec

```
requirements = pysmb, kivy==master, https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip
android.permissions = INTERNET, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, WAKE_LOCK
```

when trying to import, the application does not even open

```
from smb.SMBConnection import SMBConnection the apk closes
```

then I tried to use OS library

```
        try:
            config = configparser.ConfigParser()
            config.read('config.ini')
            db_file = config.get('database', 'db_file')
            path = r'{}'.format(db_file)
            files = os.listdir(path)
            config_screen = self.root.get_screen("config")
            config_screen.ids.text_db.text = str(files)
        except Exception as e:
            config_screen = self.root.get_screen("config")
            config_screen.ids.text_db.text = str(e)
```

config.ini

```
[database]
db_file = \\000.000.000.00\DB
```

I found the most interesting OS library is anti-python, but as I said on the computer it accesses the folder but when I run the apk it does not find the folder

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\\\\000.000.0.000\\DB'
```

the 0's are just for example,

is there any configuration in buildozer.spec that is still missing? any permission? or the code is wrong for android